# HTML/JavaScript parsing dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is probably a stupid question, but I want to use JavaScript to get the HTML from [this website](http://flashscore.com). I want data from the center of the page, but it looks to be a dynamic table (you can click tabs and the URL doesn't change, nor does the table reload); this might be AJAX? Anyway, I wrote a query that should have accessed data in the table, but it came back undefined. I tested the query on a regular table in JSFiddle, and it worked, but the same query didn't pull any information from the table. I'm getting the HTML using `XMLHttpRequest`; will this not work for such a table?

Comment: if the domain you are running your script on doesn't match that domain, then your request will fail because that is cross-site-scripting

Comment: it's def AJAX... is the linked one your website or someone else's?

Comment: @CrayonViolent it's a Chrome extension, it's in the permissions and I've already scripted from other sites

Comment: @webeno someone else's, i just want to pull info from it

Comment: What's the query that you've used?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to go about it. The first thing you are going to run into is the [Same Origin Polacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Since you are building a Chrome extension this should not be an issue, but flashscore could change their HTML in the future which would messup your website.

Rather than having your UI depend on their UI I would use an API. If you are just trying to get sports scores in general (not from flashscore) there are plenty of APIs out there. I would look specifically for a Javascript one because those are the easiest to use with a Chrome Extension. With this info you can build whatever kind interface you want. I google a few API with Javascript wrappers.

Here are a couple.

- https://github.com/bryanschoeff/soccer-scores
- https://github.com/ordepdev/scores-parser

*I am not sure how good these are, but you can give them a try.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe a headless browser (no viewport) like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) could do the trick, or you could write your own [Chrome Extension Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which injects JS when your window.location matches a pattern. You could either manually or automatically open the page (commandline `open http://http://flashscore.com/`), which would trigger your content script to run and even close itself